# BufferedImage in JFrame doesnt Show up

Tags: java, swing, jframe, bufferedimage, drawimage

trying to get an image to print into a window. Everything runs without errors, and it also works if I replace the drawImage with another graphics class. However, the window is missing the image, and i'm not sure why. Again, the JFrame stuff and Graphics work fine with drawing other graphics, but  only doesn't draw the image here. Thanks.

```
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.imageio.stream.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;

public class GraphicsMovement2 extends JApplet{
    BufferedImage image = null;

    public static void main(String args[]){
        BufferedImage image = null;
        try {
            File file = new File("C:\\Users/Jonheel/Google Drive/School/10th Grade/AP Computer Science/Junkbin/MegaLogo.png");
            ImageInputStream imgInpt = new FileImageInputStream(file);
            image = ImageIO.read(file);
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("x");
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("y");
        }


        JApplet example = new GraphicsMovement2();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Movement");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(example);
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(1366,768));       //Sets the dimensions of panel to appear when run
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public void paint (Graphics page){
    page.drawImage(image, 100, 100, 100, 100, Color.RED, this);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've defined `image` twice...

```
BufferedImage image = null;

public static void main(String args[]){
    BufferedImage image = null;
```

This essentially means that by the time you get to the `paint` method, it is `null` as you haven't initialized the instance variable.

Another problem you will have is the fact that you are trying to load the image from a static reference but the `image` isn't declared as `static`.  Better to move this logic into the constructor or instance method.

Don't use `JApplet` as your container when you're adding to a `JFrame`, you're better of using something like `JPanel`.  It will help when it comes to adding things to the container.

**YOU MUST CALL** `super.paint(g)`...in fact, **DON'T** override the `paint` method of top level containers like `JFrame` or `JApplet`.  Use something like `JPanel` and override the `paintComponent` method instead.  Top level containers aren't double buffered.

The `paint` methods does a lot of important work and it's just easier to use `JComponent#paintComponent` ... but don't forget to call `super.paintComponent`

**UPDATED**

You need to define `image` within the context it is going to be used.

Because you declared the `image` as an instance field of `GraphicsMovement2`, you will require an instance of `GraphicsMovement2` in order to reference it.

However, in you `main` method, which is `static`, you also declared a variable named `image`.

The `paint` method of `GraphicsMovement2` can't see the variable you declared in `main`, only the instance field (which is `null`).

In order to fix the problem, you need to move the loading of the image into the context of a instance of `GraphicsMovement2`, this can be best achived (in your context), but moving the image loading into the constructor of `GraphicsMovement2`

```
public GraphicsMovement2() {
    try {
        File file = new File("C:\\Users/Jonheel/Google Drive/School/10th Grade/AP Computer Science/Junkbin/MegaLogo.png");
        ImageInputStream imgInpt = new FileImageInputStream(file);
        image = ImageIO.read(file);
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("x");
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("y");
    }
}
```

The two examples below will produce the same result...

[image]

**The Easy Way**

```
public class TestPaintImage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestPaintImage();
    }

    public TestPaintImage() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new ImagePane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class ImagePane extends JPanel {

        public ImagePane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            ImageIcon icon = null;
            try {
                icon = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("/path/to/your/image")));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            add(new JLabel(icon));
        }

    }
}
```

**The Hard Way**

```
public class TestPaintImage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestPaintImage();
    }

    public TestPaintImage() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new ImagePane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class ImagePane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage background;

        public ImagePane() {
            try {
                background = ImageIO.read(new File("/path/to/your/image"));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return background == null ? super.getPreferredSize() : new Dimension(background.getWidth(), background.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (background != null) {
                int x = (getWidth() - background.getWidth()) / 2;
                int y = (getHeight() - background.getHeight()) / 2;
                g.drawImage(background, x, y, this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Take the time to read through the tutorials

- [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)
- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

Comment: That answer was a bit beyond me, do i put the 'BufferedImage image = null;' in the main method or not? I tried to not do it earlier but like you said I had problems with it being declared as static.

Comment: Thanks for the fully detailed fixes for both. Seeing both definitely changed my attitude on this. My last question before i can mark this as solved is whether I should put the ImagePane class into a new .java file. Everything else at least builds right now, and looks better too.

Comment: @Jonheel The `ImagePane` in my example should be completely independent, and from a reuse point of view, yes, it can be in it's own source file

Comment: Thank you, its just what I wanted. The stuff in graphics are still a bit above me, even after this, so when i do return to graphics, I will be sure to refer back to this.

Answer (score 2):

Your class shouldn't extend JApplet when you're not even using applets -- this makes no sense. Instead

- Have your drawing class extend JPanel
- Draw in the JPanel's paintComponent method
- Add this JPanel to the JFrame's contentPane.
- Read the [Swing painting tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html). You can't guess at this stuff and expect it to work, and the tutorials will show you how it's done correctly.

Comment: Is there not a way to avoid that? Again, even though this may not be the best way to do things, it gets the job done, plus im not expanding on this program after it displays the bufferedImage.

Comment: @user1793082: why try to do things the wrong way for no good reason? Again, it makes no sense. You could use a vice grip to bang in nails, and it would sort of work, but why continue doing this when a hammer is  much better suited for the job?

Comment: @user1793082 bagging my head against a wall will bring down the wall, but why suffer the pain...

Comment: I agree entirely, but i'm trying to limp across the finish line here. I'm not going to return to graphics for a long time after this program, so i'm not looking for a well written program right now.

Comment: @user1793082 *"I'm not going to return to graphics for a long time"* don't limit yourself, you don't know where life will drag you, kicking and screaming ;)

Comment: @jonheel: `"so i'm not looking for a well written program right now"`: Not a real great attitude. It almost makes me want to wonder why we should waste time trying to help you when we can instead spend time with a student who cares. Just hope your doctor didn't have this attitude when he was studying medicine.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Go figure, I have now spent 10+ hours going through the java swing class tutorials

Answer (score 2):

Don't mix file deviders,

> File file = new File("C:\\Users/Jonheel/Google Drive/School/10th Grade/AP Computer Science/Junkbin/MegaLogo.png");

should be replaced with:

> File file = new File("C:/Users/Jonheel/Google Drive/School/10th Grade/AP Computer Science/Junkbin/MegaLogo.png");

Comment: Good for saving me one character, but not much else. It didn't help and i had a file reading program from before that worked using the other way.