# How to draw different objects with paintComponent()?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, graphics2d, paintcomponent

I am trying to draw several things inside a `JPanel`. I am drawing shapes (works), and I also want to fill the JPanel with a picture.
But `paintComponent()` only takes one argument. And this gets complicated when I have some extra code for drawing the shapes.

My paintComponent() method is currently like this:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {


    g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    for (int i = 0; i < shapes.size(); i++) {
        Shape s = (Shape) shapes.get(i);
        if (s != null)
            g2.draw(s);
    }
}
```

I have searched around a lot and cannot find a way to do this.

Does anyone know how to do this, or maybe some workaround?

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299495/java-swing-how-to-add-an-image-to-a-jpanel

Comment: Do you have super.paintComponent(g)?

Comment: Yes, i accidently left it out because i were removing some commenting.

Comment: Thank you Ali Alamiri, but the real problem for me is that i pass in the image as a Graphics object. This gets complicated since the shapes drawn in paintComponent() is also passed in as Graphics objects.

Comment: My bad. Ignore my last comment. I just added g2.drawImage(images[0], 0, 0, null); in paintComponent(). And repaint();                 Thanks for answering guys!

Answer (score 1):

Just like your approach to drawing shapes, you need to maintain a reference to the images you want to draw within the class and reference them in much the same way.

The following are all examples of drawing images within `paintComponent`, on a verity of topics

- [BufferedImage in JFrame doesnt Show up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13188417/bufferedimage-in-jframe-doesnt-show-up/13188512#13188512)
- [Scale the ImageIcon automatically to label size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548808/scale-the-imageicon-automatically-to-label-size/14553003#14553003)
- [Jpanel resize on repaint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12797933/jpanel-resize-on-repaint/12798480#12798480)

Nb - I may be misreading this, but you should never be calling `paintComponent` yourself. It is called on your behalf by the repaint engine within Swing